# Analizar malware de Telegram de nombre BTC KEY FINDER.exe

Tags: c#, windows10, seguridad

Quería compartir con vosotros unas dudas que me surgen intentando analizar las acciones que está realizando un software descargado de Telegram, en concreto se llama BTC KEY FINDER.exe. Lo cierto es que desde primera hora sabía lo que había por las instrucciones que el usuario de esa red social indicaba, pero tenía curiosidad si minaría de forma oculta, intentaría robar mis datos, u otras formas de robarme. Por tanto lo ejecuto en una máquina virtual con Windows 10, y el primer mensaje que me sale se puede ver en la imagen 1, y una vez le digo 3 hilos empieza a simular que está probando las 12 palabras semilla en direcciones de bitcoin.

Y lo que me gustaría es poder ver ese código o ver las peticiones http/https que está ejecutando, para lo cual cuando ejecuto **dnSpy** dentro de la máquina virtual e intento hacer debug al programa sale un mensaje de **themida** que dice que se ha detectado un debugger y no se puede ejecutar el programa. Además ejecuto **Fiddler Classic** y cuando está analizando las peticiones http/https el programa se queda parado y no puedo ver las peticiones.

¿Me ayudáis para ver el código del software o decidme por dónde tirar para ampliar mis conocimientos en ciberseguridad?

Gracias.

[image: Foto 1]

[image: Foto 2]

Comment: Este sitio es sobre programacion.. pero creo que en la red hay alguno sobre ciberseguridad.. Tal vez deberias probar ahi...

Comment: Hace décadas que no veo estas cosas, así lo que te comento puede estar muy desactualizado. Al parecer el programa tiene una anti debugger, que son una serie de técnicas y trucos para impedir debuggearlo, pero básicamente es una línea de código que detectaba el debug y terminaba el programa. Lo que se hacía era decompilarlo y quitar esas líneas, me parece que algunos lo hacían hasta editando en HEX. Por otro lado si configuras un proxy quizás puedas ver a donde van las conexiones y el contenido siempre que no esté encriptado

Comment: para analizar malware como tal, ve por la distro linuxera `Remnux`, tira del `Wireshark` para ver los paquetes que se mueven a nivel de red, revisa las herramientas de `system internals` de Mark Russinovich para que puedas seguir el rastro que va modificando en los registros del windows. Es toda una movida bien interesante, te sugiero evitar darle acceso a internet a esa máquina virtual. Saludos.